# Delete Page after plugin deactivation code not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to delete page after plugin deactivate.The code is not working for delete page.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'insert_page' );

function insert_page(){
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'Menu',
  'post_content'  => 'Short Code',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => get_current_user_id(),
  'post_type'     => 'page',
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post, '' );
 $newvalue = wp_insert_post( $post, false );
update_option( 'Menu', $newvalue );
}
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'deactivate_plugin' );

function deactivate_plugin() {

$page = get_page_by_title('Menu');
wp_delete_post($page); 

}
```

I have even tried `wp_delete_post($page, true);`. It is also not working. Help me where i am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to address a few things if you don't mind:

First of all, you should work on your code indentation/formatting. **Future you thanks you**!

Second of all you're calling the [`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) function twice, but it's only working once. You can also check to see if `wp_insert_post()` returns a truthy value before calling [`update_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/).

Third, be careful with "common" function names, as you risk having redeclaration errors! Try and use [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php), [classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) or at the very least prefix your functions names to avoid future headaches.

Fourth, you don't need to set the `$error` parameter to `false` on `wp_insert_post()` as that is its default value.

Lastly, to answer your question (finally!) it's not working because [`wp_delete_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_post/) requires a Post *ID* and you're passing a Post *Object*. Instead you'll want to use `$page->ID`. Here's your code with the changes I outlined above:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'so_50960355_insert_page' );
function so_50960355_insert_page(){
    // Define my page arguments
    $page = array(
        'post_title'   => 'Menu',
        'post_content' => 'Short Code',
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'post_author'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'    => 'page',
    );

    if( $page_id = wp_insert_post( $page ) ){
        // Only update this option if `wp_insert_post()` was successful
        update_option( 'my_menu_page_id', $page_id );
    }
}

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'so_50960355_delete_page' );
function so_50960355_delete_page(){
    $page_id = intval( get_option( 'my_menu_page_id' ) );

    // Force delete this so the Title/slug "Menu" can be used again.
    wp_delete_post( $page_id, true );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. Unfortunately, It's still not working.

Comment: I wonder if you may have an issue with a page in the trash sharing the same name. Since you save the post ID as an option, you could try passing that id to `wp_delete_post` instead? I've updated the answer to accommodate

Comment: It's working now with the old code you have given. The issue arises because I have trashed pages containing the title Menu. Now I have deleted the pages permanently and tried activating and deactivating the plugin. It worked.Thank You very much.